# pageWithSidebar and button on the header shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using pageWithSidebar with a sidebar on the left. Now I'd like to add button on the top right side of the page. How could I achieve this?
http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/pageWithSidebar.html
I found dashboard but the structure doesn't look the sames as regular shiny. https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html

```
  navbarPage(
title = 'DataTable Options',
tabPanel('Display length',     DT::dataTableOutput('ex1')),
tabPanel('Length menu',        DT::dataTableOutput('ex2')),
tabPanel('No pagination',      DT::dataTableOutput('ex3')),
tabPanel('No filtering',       DT::dataTableOutput('ex4')),
tabPanel('Function callback',  DT::dataTableOutput('ex5'))
)pageWithSidebar(
 headerPanel("test"),
  sidebarPanel(
textInput("globalSearch", "Search", "")))
```

Comment: Please show your attempt at the problem

Comment: It seems pageWithSidebar can't be used in junction with a navbar. I would like to be able to add buttons on the right top corner of the page and keep a permanent left sidebar.

Comment: Have a look at the example here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967949/add-a-twitter-share-button-to-shiny-r-navbar

Comment: @PorkChop Can you have pageWithSidebar and navbarPage at the same time? because it doesn't launch properly in my case

Comment: Is there a particular need for you to use both? It doesn't feel right to me to be a preferred structure going forward. You can do most things with just one type of page

Comment: yes, I would like to have some secondary buttons on the right corner and leave the sidebar for the main features