# Add some italic text on the right side of the navbarPage in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, navbar

I am building a Shiny app where I want to add some italic text in the navbarPage at the right side. According to the question: [Shiny NavBar add additional info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392365/shiny-navbar-add-additional-info) I wrote the following code, but it doesn't work out for me:

This is some demo code I have now:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             HTML('<a style="text-decoration:none;cursor:default;color:#FFFFFF;" class="active" href="#">Dashboard</a>'), id="nav",
             navbarMenu('Graphs', icon = icon('chart-area'),
                        tabPanel('One country'),
                        tabPanel('Two countries')),
                        tabPanel('Tables'),
             tags$script(HTML("var header = $('.navbar> .container-fluid');
                       header.append('<div style=\"float:right\"><h5>Some very important text</h5></div>');
                       console.log(header)"))
  ))
                        

server <- function(input, output, session) {}
  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This results in:

1. the following warning message: *Warning message:
   Navigation containers expect a collection of `bslib::nav()`/`shiny::tabPanel()`s and/or `bslib::nav_menu()`/`shiny::navbarMenu()`s. Consider using `header` or `footer` if you wish to place content above (or below) every panel's contents.*
2. not the desired output. Because, the text is not visible, because it has the same colour as the background, the text is under the Dashboard, Graphs en tables text, but I want them to be on the same line. The text is not in italic.

[Output now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5w5c.png)

This is what I want:
[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi0Oo.png)

After the answer from lz100 it looks very nice on a big screen, but the text is still under the Dashboard, Graphs en tables text. And when I change the format of the Rshiny dashboard to my very small laptopscreen, the output becomes likes this:

[Output after answer from lz100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD459.png)

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
ui <- fluidPage(
    navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
               HTML('<a style="text-decoration:none;cursor:default;color:#FFFFFF;" class="active" href="#">Dashboard</a>'), id="nav",
               navbarMenu('Graphs', icon = icon('chart-area'),
                          tabPanel('One country',
                               tags$script(HTML(
                               "
                               var header = $('.navbar> .container-fluid');
                               header.append('<div id=\"my-title\">Some very important text</div>');
                               ")),
                               tags$style(HTML(
                                   '
                                   .navbar-collapse.collapse {display: inline-block !important;}
                                   #my-title {
                                       float:right; 
                                       display: flex; 
                                       color: white;
                                       align-items: flex-end; 
                                       justify-content: flex-end; 
                                       height: 60px; 
                                       font-style: italic;
                                   }
                                   '
                               ))
                          ),
                          tabPanel('Two countries')),
               tabPanel('Tables')
    )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

1. The reason you have warnings is because you put `tags$script` under `navbarPage`. Not a big deal to me, but I relocate your script inside the first `tabPanel`, warnings are gone.
2. Some CSS and JS added to create your desired output

[image]

Search/Read here if you don't know how these CSS work: https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Comment: Thanks for you answer! It doesn't work completely the way I wanted. The text is still under the Dashboard, Graphs en tables text. And when I change the format of the Rshiny dashboard to my very small laptopscreen, the output looks very broad, see my edited post in the top.

Comment: @waarde777  change `height: 60px; `  to adjust the position of the text